# Relation between partial derivative wrt one variable and the gradient of a frunction.

Tags: calculus

Is there any relation between partial derivative wrt one variable say $x_1$ i.e. $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}$ and the $\nabla f$ ? where $f(x_1,....x_n)$ is a function of n variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes:
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_j} = \langle \nabla f,e_j \rangle,
$$
where $e_j$ is the $j$-th vector of the canonical basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$.